# Not-So-Fluent-org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException

Tags: hibernate

i have a Object called Ticket.java with couple of attributes and corresponding set/get methods, Here i am not doing any parent-child relationship between Ticket and Meta.java(and  i don't have any hibernate mapping for this) but trying to use this common object Meta.java to fetch some additonal information of the Ticket.

```
public class Ticket implements Serializable {    
    public Long ticketNumber;
    public String description;    
    public Meta metaInfo; 
}
```

Have similar Meta object with get/set methods for stackInfo attribute,

```
public class Meta implements Serializable {    
    public String stackInfo;   
}
```

And my hbm.xml file has following

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.xxx.xx.xx.xx.user.entity">
    <class name="Ticket" table="table_1">
        <id name="TicketNumber" column="ticket_number" />
        <property name="Description" column="description"></property>
        <property name="MetaInfo.StackInfo" column="stack_details"></property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

when i try to run the test i am getting below error, so not sure why its complaining

```
org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: field [MetaInfo.StackInfo] not found on com.xxx.xx.xx.xx.user.entity.Ticket
```

I appreciate any help with this,

Answer (score 0):

The `Meta` class needs to be mapped as a [component](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#components).